# Configure Zookeeper zoodiscovery centralized and replicated mode

Tags: eclipse, osgi, apache-zookeeper, centralized

I have a problem configuring Zookeeper to work with zoodiscovery mode centralized and replicated. The guide at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zookeeper_Based_ECF_Discovery is a little mysterious about that.

I'm working on Windows XP SP3, Java JDK 1.6, Eclipse STS 2.7.2, org.eclipse.osgi 3.7 and a proxied network.

NOTE: Using the standalone configuration mode gives no problem. I use *-Dzoodiscovery.flavor.standalone=192.168.23.21:3030;clientPort=3031* on the server and *-Dzoodiscovery.flavor.standalone=192.168.23.28:3031;clientPort=3030* and it works nicely.

I will split the question in multiple parts:

1) In a setup with a (one) central server on 192.168.23.28, multiple clients. The clients will both publish and consume services.

I launch the server as:

```
java -Dzoodiscovery.dataDir=name -Dzoodiscovery.flavor=zoodiscovery.flavor.centralized=192.168.23.28 -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar -console -consoleLog -clean -configuration c:\temp\osgiserver\configuration
```

I can see the *ZooDiscovery> Discovery Service Activated.*

When I launch the clients (in the example there's only one) as:

```
java -Dzoodiscovery.autoStart=true -Dzoodiscovery.flavor=zoodiscovery.flavor.centralized=192.168.23.28 -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar -console -consoleLog -clean -configuration c:\temp\osgiclient\configuration
```

I can see *ZooDiscovery> Discovery Service Activated.* but then *INFO - Attempting connection to server: /192.168.23.28* which goes on and on never succeeding.

I have to start server and clients by configuring Zookeeper from command line, I cannot insert those parameters inside the bundles. I have tried setting the *-Dzoodiscovery.clientPort=8888* on the server (8888 is available) and then *-Dzoodiscovery.flavor=zoodiscovery.flavor.centralized=192.168.23.28:8888* on the client, but still it changes nothing.

How do I configure such a setup?

2) Plus I'd like to know if it's possible, using centralized, to have multiple central servers talking between them or if I'd have to use the replicated mode.

3) Which leads to.. how do I configure server and clients to use replicated mode by passing VM command line arguments?

4) In replicated mode, if I add a new Zookeeper instance later on, will I have to stop and reconfigure the existing Zookeeper instances to work with the new one or is it sufficient to configure the new one to work with the existing ones?

Thank you very much,

cheers

Comment: Have you tried Configuration Admin? I've answered something related with that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723910/changing-the-server-address-ecf-uses-when-it-looks-up-remote-services/7270569#7270569). You can change instance service properties in execution time, but I'm not sure if is the thing you want (not an expert in zookeper, sorry).

Comment: @PabloGarcía: Thank you, yes, I found something in the lines of it. Problem is, I must configure it from command-line / JVM parameters, I cannot write any code to do it for me (this is a mandatory requirement)